# Concatenate variable in function name - javascript

Tags: javascript

im trying to build a for loop so I dont waste code lines by repeating the same code for a function but im not doing it right, I need help on how to concatenate my loop variable (i) so i can change the name of the function. Here is my function code:

```js
<script>
for (i = 1; i < 90; i++) { 
var nome = window["mostra" + i];
function nome() { 
  document.getElementById("form"+i).style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("texto"+i).style.display="none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: window["mostra" + i]=function(){ ...} <<- very very bad style

Comment: Explain your code or requirement

Comment: I suggest that you pass a parameter to the function, insted of creating 90 functions

Comment: I want to have multiple functions so i can do the function on multiple objects thats why i cant have the same function name/id of the object for all

Comment: So there are already properties on `window` with the names `mostra1`, `mostra2`, etc., and you want to create functions with those names? This sounds like an X/Y problem: What's the underlying thing you're trying to do that makes you think you need to do this?

Comment: Very bad idea. please explain what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Instead have a common function which accepts a parameter.

Comment: Just use parameters in your function.

Comment: just use a parameter in your function

Comment: can u guys explain how to use parameters, because im new in js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to build 89 functions named mostra*i* . You can achieve it like this:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 90; i++) { // <- the let is very important
     window["mostra" + i]=function() { // <- assign the function to mostra*i*
     document.getElementById("form"+i).style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("texto"+i).style.display="none";
    };
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="mostra1()">Test it!</button>
<div id="form1" style="display:none">Will show</div>
<div id="texto1">Will hide</div>
```

However, its very very bad style. You may just pass it:

```
function mostra(i){//one function instead of 89
 document.getElementById("form"+i).style.display="block";
 document.getElementById("texto"+i).style.display="none";
}
```

So you can do:

```
mostra(1);//instead of mostra1()
```

Or in html:

```
<button onclick="mostra(1)" >show first</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example of using a parameter in a function:

```
function add2(i) { // <--- name it here
    return i + 2; // <--- use it here
}
add2(3); // <--- call it here
// ==> 5
```

Try thinking about how this could help with your problem!